# How can I return server side error to the client's HTML page in Express/node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an web app I which the user requests to create an account. The request from client's page will reach the server and query the database. Now what is the proper way of displaying `User already exists` error in my registeration page. In short, how can I send server side errors to my clients in Node JS?

Answer (score -1):

There are some options to get what you need. The approach that I would not follow will be using the http protocol and sending a 500 response for example.

One good approach would be creating a status and a message fields in your response.

You could use code 200 for the sucessful requests and a different code for the rest.  You could have a dedicated code to inform the api user that the backend coud not insert the data.

Example response:

```
  {   

code: 789   

message: "User could not be inserted" 

...

     }
```